# ERROR TypeError: this.homeboxsp.map is not a function at patchForm

Tags: angular, typescript, patch

I have this patchForm in my code:

```
populateForm() {
    this.hsP.homeboxPGetAll().subscribe(
      homeboxsp => {
        this.homeboxsp = homeboxsp
        let controls = {
          'homeboxpackage_id': new FormControl('', Validators.required)
        };
        for (let i = 0; i < this.homeboxsp.length; i++) {
          controls['active-' + this.homeboxsp[i].homeboxpackage_id] = new FormControl(this.homeboxsp[i].active === 1, Validators.required)
        }
        this.activeHomeboxPForm = new FormGroup(controls);
        this.patchForm();
      }
    )
  }
      patchForm() {
        this.activeHomeboxPForm.patchValue({
          homeboxpackage_id: this.homeboxsp.map(x => x.homeboxpackage_id),
        });
      }
```

Service.ta

```
public homeboxPGetAll(): Observable<HomeboxP[]> {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('x-access-token', this.auth.getCurrentUser().token);
    return this.http.get(Api.getUrl(Api.URLS.homeboxPGetAll), {
      headers: headers
    })
      .map((response: Response) => {
        let res = response.json();
        if (res.StatusCode === 1) {
          this.auth.logout();
        } else if (res.StatusCode === 4) {
          return false;
        } else if (res.StatusDescription === 'No result') {
          return false;
        } else {
          return res.StatusDescription.map(homeboxP => {
            return new HomeboxP(homeboxP);
          });
        }
      });
  }
```

When API get data this error doesn't show.
When API get empty data in console show this error:

> ERROR TypeError: this.homeboxsp.map is not a function
>       at HomeboxComponent.patchForm

Can you ask me any idea please, how to solve this error?

Comment: please provide the body of `homboxPGetAll()` function. I think I can solve this error by taking a look at it.

Comment: might be homeboxsp variable is not an array. We are applying Array.map to null value.

Comment: @NguyễnThanhTú I edit my post. Thank you!

Comment: @NguyễnThanhTú Have you any idea please?

Comment: I really want to help. However, it would be much easier if you also make this project available on CodeSandbox and share its link. This way, your question could be easily answered.